# ¿Son válidas las preguntas del tipo "Cómo resolver esto en cualquier lenguaje"?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, temática

Hace unos días veía alguno de esos problemas básicos de la programación, resueltos en un determinado lenguaje y pensaba: qué fácil sería hacerlo en 'X' o qué complicado es hacerlo en 'Y'. Por ello, me planteaba:

**¿Es válido plantear un problema y pedir soluciones en múltiples lenguajes**

A mí particularmente siempre me resultaron muy informativas esas comparaciones. La idea es que cada experto en determinados lenguajes aporte lo suyo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No debes hacer una pregunta pidiendo respuestas en **múltiples** lenguajes. Esto significa pedir varias respuestas distintas que no es apropiado para nuestro formato de pregunta/respuesta.
Lo que sí puedes es hacer varias preguntas. Una por lenguaje que te interese. No es problema si son casi iguales salvo por el lenguaje en que se pide la respuesta. Eso sí, debieras demostrar que realmente te interesan esas preguntas poniendo código que has intentado en cada lenguaje distinto en que preguntes.

Pero sí puedes hacer una pregunta para **cualquier** lenguaje. En este caso te da igual el lenguaje en que te respondan, te vale cualquier lenguaje. Pero solo necesitas una respuesta, sea cual sea el lenguaje.

Esto último es apropiado para preguntas algorítmicas del tipo de:

- ¿Cómo ordeno una lista de enteros?
- [Manera mas eficaz de comparar dos arreglos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/39680/manera-mas-eficaz-de-comparar-dos-arreglos)
- ¿Que estructura de datos puedo usar para mantener una lista ordenada de números con operaciones eficientes de inserción, borrado y consulta de existencia?

Cuando el autor hace una pregunta así y la marca como [lenguaje-agnostico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lenguaje-agnostico) significa que le interesa el concepto algorítmico y no una implementación concreta. Ya se encargará él de implementarlo en  su lenguaje favorito.

Estas preguntas se pueden responder usando un pseudolenguaje de programación o cualquier lenguaje de programación real. Quien ha trabajado con varios lenguajes de programación procedurales puede entender una respuesta en que se use un lenguaje procedural que nunca ha usado.
Sí que puede ser interesante especificar el tipo de paradigma de programación que te interesa :

- Programación procedural
- Programación lógica
- Programación funcional

Quien no ha hecho nunca programación funcional posiblemente no entienda una respuesta que usa ese paradigma por muy experimentado que sea en lenguajes procedurales. Si no especificas paradigma la mayoría asumirá el paradigma procedural, que es el más utilizado.

Una ventaja de formular la pregunta así es que aumentas el número de personas que puede responder lo cual facilita tener mejores respuestas. Si realmente te da igual el lenguaje de implementación entonces es la mejor forma de responder.

La aceptación no es un problema.

> El aceptar una respuesta no es obligatorio; no te sientas presionado a
>   aceptar la primera respuesta que recibas. Espera hasta que recibas la
>   respuesta que conteste tu pregunta de la mejor manera.

No es obligatorio. Puedes no aceptar ninguna respuesta. O puedes aceptar la primera que conteste tu pregunta de la mejor manera. Que haya otras igual de buenas en otros lenguajes no es un problema. A quien usa el tag de lenguaje-agnostico no le aportarán nada nuevo pues vista la solución en un lenguaje vista en todos los del mismo paradigma. Pero pueden ser útiles para otros usuarios menos experimentados.

Comment: Gracias Jose, pero el tema de estas preguntas es que justamente el que la/las respuesta/s muestren las implementaciones en distintos lenguajes, a eso apuntaba mi pregunta, creo que el comentario de @Mariano termina de cerrar la idea que tenía.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Ok, releyento tu pregunta ya veo el matiz. Voy a editar mi respuesta.

Comment: Luego de la edición quedó muy completa, y creo que cubre el tema totalmente.

Answer (score 3):

Si preguntas por cómo resolver un problema en 2 o más lenguajes es un problema demasiado amplio para el sitio y sería mejor dividirlo en múltiples preguntas, 1 por cada lenguaje deseado.

Adicional a esto, si la pregunta está más orientada a diseño y análisis de algoritmos, de componentes de software, arquitectura de software y demás, que no necesariamente se vinculan a un LP en particular. En estos casos, las respuestas pueden proveer una implementación en un LP para reforzar la idea expuesta, de modo que no sea una respuesta tan abstracta.

Ejemplos de esto (en el sitio en inglés):

- [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/79923/1065197) (¿Qué son la pila y el cúmulo?)
- [How to pair socks from a pile efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14415881/1065197) (¿Cómo emparejar las medias de una pila eficientemente?)

Comment: Claro y breve. Eso del cúmulo es la primera vez que lo leo, estoy demasiado acostumbrado al inglés, pero me alegra verlo escrito así.

Comment: "cola" de donde vengo yo.

Answer (score 2):

Voy a arriesgar una respuesta: **creo que no**, a pesar que sería un tipo de contenido que me gustaría ver. Las contras que le veo:

- Bajo que etiqueta ponemos la pregunta
- Sería un tipo de pregunta que no debiera tener una respuesta aceptada
- El que viene a buscar una respuesta para un lenguaje en particular tendría que desplazarse por una serie larga de respuestas hasta encontrar lo que busca.

Comment: El punto principal es el segundo: ¿cuál sería la respuesta aceptada? El formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio busca preguntar con una única respuesta válida. No obstante, hay preguntas generales cuya única respuesta válida no depende del lenguaje (que no es exactamente lo mismo que estás preguntando). Para esos casos, se usa la etiqueta [TAG:lenguaje-agnóstico], y se pueden encontrar algunos ejemplos ahí... Aunque justo después de comentar, vi que hay algunas preguntas que tenemos que reetiquetar correctamente sacándole esa etiqueta :-)

Answer (score 2):

**Pedir soluciones en múltiples lenguajes** hace la pregunta demasiado amplia, así que este tipo de preguntas **deberían ser cerradas**.

Como se ha explicado en algunas de las respuestas previas a esta, sería válido hacer una pregunta que sea independiente del lenguaje de programación pero que se pida que se incluya código en un lenguaje en el que sea posible implementar el concepto o algoritmo del cual trata la pregunta.